# bad tags suggested for deletion

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow

'give' 'givemethecode'

Currently, the only questions with these are from someone with rep 1. So he or she can't have created them. I submit that they are lame.

Comment: Is there an approved tag for these kinds of questions? I know some people will maintain that if they are bad they will be closed and if they are not bad they should be answered. But I think applying a tag to the 'please do my job/homework' type questions is helpful to people like me who don't want to waste time even looking at them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were probably added by the subsequent editors of the question.

Comment: Indeed they were. But either way; gone now.

Comment: I wish tag creation was a downvotable action.